# How to source admin credentials to gain access to admin-only CLI commands in Openstack's Nova?

Tags: openstack, centos7, openstack-nova

According to [this documentation](http://docs.openstack.org/juno/install-guide/install/yum/content/ch_nova.html) the admin credentials need to be sourced as follows:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ source admin-openrc.sh
-bash: admin-openrc.sh: No such file or directory
```

The suspicion is that this is required to run the following commands:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ nova service-list
ERROR (CommandError): You must provide a username or user id via --os-username, --os-user-id, env[OS_USERNAME] or env[OS_USER_ID]
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ nova image-list
ERROR (CommandError): You must provide a username or user id via --os-username, --os-user-id, env[OS_USERNAME] or env[OS_USER_ID]
```

Comment: How did you install OpenStack? Did you _look_ in your directory to see if the script has a different name?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Installed via yum as root. The script does neither exist in /home/root nor in /home/user

Answer (score 0):

you can download the admin-openrc file from horizon, under:

> Compute => API Access => Download Openstack RC file